# make a api call for each object on the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this method:

```
updateCustomers = (input) => {

    //let urls = input

    let urls=[{
        name: "localhost:8081",
        url: "http://localhost:8081"
    },
    {
        name: "localhost:8082",
        url: "http://localhost:8081"
    },
    {
        name: "localhost:8083",
        url: "http://localhost:8081"
    }]

    alert( urls.length)
    urls.map((url, index) => {

        let paramsNode = {
            customer: this.props.match.params.customer,
            environment: this.props.match.params.environment,
            action: 'check',
            node: url.name
        }
        console.log("url: "+url.name)
        console.log("***********************")
        this.gatewayService.manageServices(paramsNode, (callback) => this.checkServiceNode(callback, index, url))
    })

}
```

Pls ignore the paramsNode variable, what I want to show is that I want to make an api call for each member of my list.

This is my api call:

```
manageServices=(params,callback)=>{

    let url = this.baseUrl;

    if(params.customer == null || params.environment == null) {
        throw "The customer or environment parameter cant be null.";
    }

    url += "/" + params.customer + "/" + params.environment +  "/"+params.node  +"/configurations/manageServices/" + params.action;

    url = encodeURI(url);

    RestUtils.fetchJsonFromApi(url,callback);

}
```

And this is the RestUtils method:

```
static fetchJsonFromApi(url, callback) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log("fetchJsonFromApi " + JSON.stringify(json))
            // making callback optional
            if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
                callback(json);
            }
            return json;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

When the call is done it executes this method:

```
 checkServiceNode = (result, index,node) => {
    console.log("--------------------------")
    console.log("HERE"+node.name)
    console.log("##########################")
 }
```

What I wanted to do is to print this values in this sequence:

```
     url: localhost:8081
     ***********************
   --------------------------
    HERE localhost:8081
    ##########################

    url: localhost:8082
     ***********************
   --------------------------
    HERE localhost:8082
    ##########################

    url: localhost:8083
     ***********************
   --------------------------
    HERE localhost:8083
    ##########################
```

But what I get is this (the order is always random):

```
    url: localhost:8081
    ***********************
    url: localhost:8082
    ***********************
    url: localhost:8083
    ***********************

    --------------------------
    HERE localhost:8082
    ##########################

    --------------------------
    HERE localhost:8083
    ##########################
    --------------------------
    HERE localhost:8081
    ##########################
```

How can I ensure the order of my prints?

Comment: Because of calling API asynchronously, so every call request will return response independently once it completes (you see random). If you want to order call requests, try to use callback (only execute calling next request when previous request is done)

Comment: You seem to be forgetting one major feature of javascript. It's asynchronous nature.

Comment: but I am using callbacks @thanhphan

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.map` does not wait for the current API call to be completed before making the next one. Therefore sequence of API calls completion depends on a network latency and other factors which make the sequence mostly non deterministic.

If you want to make API calls in a sequence (on by one) you can write a function that will process every next url after the previous promise (api call) is resolved, for example it may be implemented as follows:

```
const asyncSeries = (fn, items) => items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc.then(collection =>
    fn(item).then(result =>
      collection.concat(result)
    )
  )
}, Promise.resolve([]));
```

In order to make it work you need make the function that sends api calls (`manageServices`) **return** the promise:

```
return RestUtils.fetchJsonFromApi(url,callback);
```

Then you can make API calls in series as follows:

```
asyncSeries((url, index) => {

  let paramsNode = {
    customer: this.props.match.params.customer,
    environment: this.props.match.params.environment,
    action: 'check',
    node: url.name
  }
  console.log("url: "+url.name)
  console.log("***********************")
  return this.gatewayService.manageServices(paramsNode, (callback) => this.checkServiceNode(callback, index, url))
}, urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `fetch` to make the call to the endpoints, and `fetch` works with promises. There is a method on the `Promise` object called `all` which takes a list of promises as arguments and resolves when all of them resolve individually. On the `then` callback, it passes as the first argument, a list with the resolved result of each promise.

[Here is the documentation for the `Promise.all` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all)

And here is an elementary example of how you could use it. To simplify the case, I override the `fetch` function with a mock, that resolves after a random amount of time. So that on each run, every promise resolves in a different order. However, the `result` of the `Promise.all` call returns in the same order they were called.

```
function fetch(url) {
  var randomTimeout = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000, 0)
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() { resolve({url:url, timeout: randomTimeout}) }, randomTimeout);
  });
}

function callMultipleAPI(urlList) {
  return Promise.all(urlList.map(function (url) { return fetch(url); }));
}

var urlList = ['http://localhost:8081/', 'http://localhost:8082/', 'http://localhost:8083'];

callMultipleAPI(urlList)
  .then(function(result) { console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); });

/*
Result:
[
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:8081/",
    "timeout": 869
  },
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:8082/",
    "timeout": 508
  },
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:8083",
    "timeout": 269
  }
]
*/
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use **async**/**await** already in 2019:

```js
  let urls=[{
    name: "localhost:8081",
    url: "http://localhost:8081"
  },
  {
    name: "localhost:8082",
    url: "http://localhost:8081"
  }]

  const promises = []

  // make asynchronous api call for each endpoint
  // and save promise of call in array
  for(const url of urls) {
    promises.push(fetch(url.url))
    console.log(`endpoint ${url.name} called`)
  }

  const results = []

  // asyncronously await all of the calls and push result in same order
  for(const promise of promises) {
    results.push(await promise))
    // or use result right now
  }

  // use array of results as you need
  for(const result of results) {
    console.log(result)
  }

  // or with positioned access
  results.map( (result, pos) => {
    console.log(`endpoint ${urls[pos]} result: `, result)
  })
```